# CSS Ajax loader bottom-centered positioning issues

Tags: css

I am trying to position this ajax-loader gif file bottom banner centered on all the main browsers - Mac Chrome/Firefox/Safari and Windows IE 8.

I am following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/).

The CSS in this tutorial for the ajax-loader is positioned at the top right corner of the banner (see demo page), using:

```
  #load {  
        display: none;  
        position: absolute;  
        rightright: 10px;  
        top: 10px;  
        background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif);  
        width: 43px;  
        height: 11px;  
        text-indent: -9999em;  
    }
```

Using this css for #load, how to position bottom centered under the big green tickbox of this same example and also work on all popular browsers mentioned above?

Comment: In order for this to work, you will have to set the parents div position to `relative`, so that this load will be absolutely positioned against the parent div and not the whole document, and still I don't get it what is you problem here

Comment: thanks for the reply c0mrade - all I am unsure how to do, is move the loader image from the top right to the bottom center. I just want to know how to reposition the loader image from where it is now to the bottom center of the banner.

Answer (score 1):

```
#wrapper{
  position:relative;
}
#load{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  bottom:0px;
  position:absolute;
  background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif) top center no-repeat;
}
```

Wrapper needs to be relative, load needs to be absolute